# Understanding difference between $p_{X,Y}(x, y) $ and $p_{X|Y}(x|y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

Let $X, Y$ be two discrete random variables. Then  $p_{X,Y}(x, y) $ is combined PMF of $X$ and $Y$. That means for some value of $x,y$ what is its probability.

But conditional PMF $p_{X|Y}(x|y)$ means what is $P(X=x)$ if we know $P(Y=y)$

I am not able to understand how they are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interested in the difference of the joint probability distribution between random random variables $X$ and $Y$, versus the conditional probability of $X$ given $Y$.

First, you should be aware of the relation

$P_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{P_{X,Y}(x,y)}{P_Y(y)}$.

Next I'll try to give some intuitive example.

The meaning is that given the occurrence of $Y$, say, a realization of random variable $Y=y$, then the distribution of $X$ will be determined depending on such realization.

Think of an example, $Y$ denotes the probability of selecting either a coin or a dice, and $X$ describes the probabilities of tossing what you choose in the first experiment (say, the coin or the dice).

Thus, if you choose the coin ($Y=\text{coin}$), you have one distribution of $X$ conditioned that your choice was a coin, say uniform $1/2$ for head and tails $\{H, T\}$ , and you have another distribution conditioned you choose the dice $Y=\text{dice}$, i.e. the distribution of $X$ given $Y=\text{dice}$ is uniform $1/6$ over the set of dice outcomes $\{1,...,6 \}$.

Comment: Ok so let me say, the conditional pmf $p_{X|Y}$ denotes that when we know $Y=y$, then out of that how many events are there such that $X=x$. But combined pmf $p_{X,Y}$ denotes that out of whole sample space how many of them have $X=x$ and $Y=y$.

Comment: I just edited the answer,  but it is missing the joint part. For this imagine that you are interested in the probability that you choose the dice, and the outcome is a 6. Then you can build a table with all the probabilities, and, its corresponding probabilities.